# IE9 stick favourites panel to left side

Tags: bookmarks, internet-explorer-9

IE8 used to have the favourites panel on the left side, now IE9 has moved it to the right side. There is a button that moves it to the left side, but the settings does not persist. After you close the panel and re-open, it comes up on the right again.

Answer (score 1):

total random guess, but some programs I notice can't save settings or write them to registry unless you run the program as an administrator. Try that?

Comment: +1, if you leave the bar open, then it sticks to the left side. as soon as you close it though it goes back to the right